# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] android.os.Bundle.getByteArray〜というエラーが発生する。

Tags: android, android-studio

Androidで、アクティビティから別のアクティビティに画像を受けわたす処理を書いているのですが、親のアクティビティに戻るときに以下のエラーが発生するのですが、原因がわかりません。
エラーの解決策を教えていただきたいです。
***java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference***

以下が子アクティビティのコードです。

```
public class PhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Bitmap bmp;
    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_filter);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray(CropActivity.EXTRA_CROPPED_IMAGE);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

以下は親アクティビティです。

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray(MainActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    mCropView = findViewById(R.id.cropImageView);
    mCropView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}

// 一部コード省略...

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_next) {
        croppedBitmap = mCropView.getCroppedBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        croppedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Intent intent = new Intent(CropActivity.this, PhotoFilterActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CROPPED_IMAGE, byteArray);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

以下はAndroidManifestに指定しているactivityエレメントです。

```
<activity android:name=".PhotoFilterActivity"
        android:label="Third Activity"
        android:parentActivityName=".CropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.test.CropActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: すみません、肝心のエラー部分のコードが抜けていました。（親アクティビティのonCreateメソッド。）
どうやら、親アクティビティ(CropActivity)の親アクティビティ(MainActivity)からのインテントができないのでNullになってしまっているようです。
こういう場合は、Fragmentを使って画面遷移を行った方が良いでしょうか？

Comment: AndroidManifest.xmlの対象とする親アクティビティと子アクティビティ各々のactivity要素に android:launchMode="singleTop" を書き足すことで、新しいアクティビティの作成を防ぐことができ、解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml の対象とする親アクティビティと子アクティビティ各々のactivity要素に `android:launchMode="singleTop"` を書き足すことで、新しいアクティビティの作成を防ぐことができ、解決しました。

---

*この投稿は [@ayana sakai さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50853/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-byte-android-os-bundle-getbytearray-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e7%99%ba#comment53162_50853) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*